# plotly map does not display geometries

Tags: plotly, mapping

I am trying to plot a geodataframe of polygons making up part of British Columbia using plotly. I have plotted the gdf using geopandas so I know the geometries are ok. When I attempt to use the plotly syntax for plotting a geodataframe using the geometry column in place of a json file, the plot opens a window in the browser with a legend and a colour bar but no map int the box.

```
pacificrange_CP_web.to_crs(pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), inplace=True)

fig = px.choropleth(pacificrange_CP_web, 
                geojson=pacificrange_CP_web.geometry, 
                locations=pacificrange_CP_web.polyid, 
                color="protected")
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", 
            visible=False)

fig.show()
```

The way I understand it, plotly does noto support any crs the way that geopandas does. So in the first line I reproject.

Additionally, I am shaky on the locations prompt. I assume this is a method to identify individual plygons within the choropleth?

I have also tried converting the gdf to a json file and using that for the geometries and linking the two but that is for another question.

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- used your sample geometry from GitHub
- it's clear this geometry has too many parts to effectively plot with **plotly**

  - created utility function `reduce_geometry()` that has three approaches to reducing geometries that are *MultiPolygon*
  - can use `size`, `percentile` or `topn`.  Have demonstrated `topn` which used only biggest *N* geometries in *MultiPolygon*
  - this function also has mode to get transparency of what it has done.  `join()` this info onto *GeoDataFrame* (it's used in `hover_data`)
  - *MultiGeometry* still means hover text is somewhat odd where it shows up. Optionally `explode()` geometry to just polygons
- it is not EPSG:4326 so projected to make it work with **plotly**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# fmt: off
# download boundaries
url = "https://github.com/maxduso/pacificrange_CP_web/blob/85b3005c0d95e838f9e18e1e7923e90adfbba682/pacificrange_subset.zip?raw=true"

f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
# fmt: on

if False and f.exists():
    f.unlink()

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# load downloaded boundaries
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(str(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath(f"{f.stem}.shp")))

# utility function to reduce number of polygons in multipolygon
# one of following can be passed
#   size - minimum size of a polygon within multiploygon
#   percentile - for example 95, take 5% largest polygons
#   topn - take largest n polygons
def reduce_geometry(g, size=None, percentile=None, topn=None, info=False):
    if isinstance(g, shapely.geometry.Polygon):
        if info:
            return {"minarea": g.area, "polycount": 1, "kept": 1}
        else:
            return g
    if percentile:
        size = np.percentile([p.area for p in g.geoms], percentile)
    elif topn:
        topn = min(topn, len(g.geoms))
        size = sorted([p.area for p in g.geoms])[-topn]
    polys = [p for p in g.geoms if p.area >= size]
    infod = {"minarea": size, "polycount": len(g.geoms), "kept": len(polys)}

    if info:
        return infod
    if len(polys) == 1:
        return polys[0]
    elif len(polys) == 0:
        return g.geoms[np.argmax([p.area for p in g.geoms])]
    else:
        return shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(polys)


# simplify geometry, take biggest n polygons in each multipolygon
# join info of this process onto data frame for transparency
TOPN = 20
gdf2 = gdf2.join(
    gdf2["geometry"].apply(reduce_geometry, topn=TOPN, info=True).apply(pd.Series)
)
gdf2["geometry"] = gdf2["geometry"].apply(reduce_geometry, topn=TOPN)

# optionally explode multipolygons into polygons (means hover text is better...)
EXPLODE=True
if EXPLODE:
    gdf2 = pd.merge(
        gdf2.drop(columns="geometry"),
        gdf2["geometry"].explode(index_parts=True).reset_index(),
        left_index=True,
        right_on="level_0",
    ).assign(
        source_polyid=lambda d: d["polyid"],
        polyid=lambda d: d.loc[:, ["polyid", "level_1"]]
        .astype(str)
        .apply("_".join, axis=1)
    )

# make geopandas data frame compatible with question code...
pacificrange_CP_web = (
    gdf2.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
    .set_index("polyid", drop=False)
)

fig = px.choropleth(
    pacificrange_CP_web,
    geojson=pacificrange_CP_web.geometry,
    locations=pacificrange_CP_web.polyid,
    hover_name="name_e",
    hover_data=["polycount","kept"],
    color="protected",
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False).update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0}
)
```

[image]

#### mapbox choropleth

```
layout = dict(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {
            "lon": sum(pacificrange_CP_web.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
            "lat": sum(pacificrange_CP_web.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
        },
        "zoom": 7,
    },
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
)

px.choropleth_mapbox(
    pacificrange_CP_web,
    geojson=pacificrange_CP_web.geometry,
    locations="polyid",
    hover_name="name_e",
    hover_data=["polycount", "kept"],
    color="protected",
).update_layout(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow how in-depth, Thanks so much Rob! Hmm so I started just with your fig=... onwards and that created a plot but it looked like lines radiating from a central point with colour. I was assuming this was because there was a problem with the geometry at some point. DO you think a "fix geometry" in QGIS might solve this problem? I then added the code block where the index is set with updated geodataframe and without the addition of the "protected" column as I already had it. The result was back to having a white space where the figure should be.

Comment: I've not used QGIS so cannot comment as such.  do you load a shape file into `pacificrange_CP_web`?  I suspect there is something wrong with the geometry / definitions of polygons.  how does `pacificrange_CP_web.boundary.plot()` look?  show the boundaries of regions in BC?

Comment: So the pacificrange_CP_web is just a subset of BC. but yes it does plot the boundaries of the area it is intended to when using that line. Don't know if there is a good way of inserting images in a comment here. Additionally I did find some geometry problems and fixed them in QGIS. However, doing that did not change my outcome since my above comment. To clarify I am only using the following part of your code as I believe the rest you used to create a comparable dataset to mine.

Comment: `pacificrange_CP_web = (
    pacificrange_CP_comp.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
    .set_index("polyid", drop=False)
    )`    `fig = px.choropleth(
    pacificrange_CP_web,
    geojson=pacificrange_CP_web.geometry,
    locations=pacificrange_CP_web.polyid,
    color="protected",
)`    `fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)`

Comment: two things: 1) it you run all of my code do you get same result?  (i.e. rule out environment issues).  2) could you share you shape data as a zip file on a cloud drive / GitHub ? (so I can check it)

Comment: I have observed behaviour you describe before, it was inconsistent geometry in another CRS when projected to EPSG:4326 gave effectively overflow issues

Comment: I hope this [link](https://github.com/maxduso/pacificrange_CP_web/blob/34d11615f74b6c203d289a710bf3abf7fe3d663c/pacificrange_subset.shp) works. It should be noted that this file is a subset of the subset set because the original file was too large to upload to a repository. It is also in EPSG: 3005 as I was using python to reproject instead of QGIS and this is straight from QGIS. Also, I tried your code and it worked as expected.

Comment: I can access that file, however can't load it as it needs also (.shx, .prj, .dbf).  do you have those also?

Comment: oh sorry. Hence the zip file. Here is the zip. [link](https://github.com/maxduso/pacificrange_CP_web/blob/85b3005c0d95e838f9e18e1e7923e90adfbba682/pacificrange_subset.zip)

Comment: I've updated answer to use your geometry.  I found that multipolygon geometry with large number of embedded polygons was causing issues... my laptop was grinding to a halt,  and hover text was making no sense.  Just excluded two rows and it works well

Comment: Holy moly thank you for all your help! I am just going through and trying to make this work for the entire dataframe. For some reason, the block which gets rid of the extra-large Multi polygons doesn't seem to work when passed the larger dataset. Do you know if there is a way of decoupling the multi polygons into single polygons or if that would even fix the issue?

Comment: I've further updated, to take account of multiple approaches to simplifying geometry and also show explode as you requested.  Hopefully this is good enough to be accepted and upvoted :-)

Comment: Wow I can't thank you enough for your help Rob.  I think that the entire dataset may just be too large for my computer to handle because your solution seems to work on everything but the whole of BC

Comment: I did land up rebuilding my whole env as the dataset was killing my laptop.  logically thinking every polygon will use resources in the browser and too many polygons brings machine to a complete halt !